# Unable to access class in App_Code from code behind in ASP.Net Website Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-code

I have been using ASP.Net's website project from last 5years, but haven't caught in problem as such, i have created new website project using DotNetNuke, added classes in App_Code folder, now when i try to access the class from code behind, i don't get any intellisense for the class/methods, i even tried wrapping class inside a namespace, that too didn't helped, can anyone point me to right direction, here's my code:
Class in App_code.

```
public class Markaz
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get list of all markaz in cache form
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List<Entities.Markaz></returns>
    public List<Entities.Markaz> GetAllMarkaz()
    {
        List<Entities.Markaz> list = DataCache.GetCache<List<Entities.Markaz>>("MarkazList");
        if (list == null)
        {
            list = CBO.FillCollection<Entities.Markaz>(Data.Markaz.GetAllMarkaz());
            DataCache.SetCache("MarkazList", list);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a web site or web application project?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your `.cs` files are not compile at all. Select your `.cs` file from the solution explorer window and on the properties window set `Built Action` to `Compile` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Do not copy`